# Finding solr on a server

Tags: python, solr

I am taking over a website which has a solr somewhere on the server. I didn't really care about it, till now when it crashed. I am trying to figure out how to restart it. The documentation say : `/bin/solr start`but it is not located there....
How can I find the rnunable file to re-launch to start again the solr server ?
I tried a `locate solr` but it gives hundred of lines (we use Flask / Python).
Here is the solr xml if it could be of any help...

```
jxd@dweb1:/etc/solr$ cat solr.xml
    <cores adminPath="/admin/cores">
    <core name="places" instanceDir="places">
    <property name="dataDir" value="places/data"/>
    </core>
    <core name="pv2" instanceDir="pv2">
    <property name="dataDir" value="pv2/data"/>
    </core>
    <core name="places_v3" instanceDir="places_v3">
    <property name="dataDir" value="places_v3/data"/>
    </core>
    <core name="ratp" instanceDir="ratp">
    <property name="dataDir" value="ratp/data"/>
    </core>
    <core name="addresses" instanceDir="addresses">
    <property name="dataDir" value="addresses/data"/>
    </core>
   </cores>
</solr>
```

Comment: first you should try to find if Solr was being executed from it's built in server (Jetty) or a production server (like tomcat)

Comment: I guess it is through jetty

Comment: then this might give you some guidance: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Running+Solr+on+Jetty

Comment: Was the answer your received useful? If yes, consider accepting/voting on the answer to make it easier for others to find it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you found your Solr home, that's where your solr.xml file lives. Your solr instances are under that. What you are trying to find is who is pointing at that home.

The variable that points at solr.home is *solr.solr.home*. You may remember that if you do Solr tutorial.

So, I'd recommend grepping the filesystem (probably start with /etc really, the /var/logs, then the rest) for "solr.solr.home" (yes, "solr" is twice there). That should give you the configuration file that pointed at Solr. From the location/format of that file, you can figure out whether it is Tomcat or Jetty or whatever (just Google the name of the file or the strangest looking tag inside if unsure).

Then, finally, you need to figure out how you started that server. If - before - you could have restarted the service and Solr would still be there, then it is probably run as a service. So, you need to look for possible services that start (tomcat or jetty). You can probably grep for the that name (case insensitive) in /var/logs or similar and look for error or information messages. Normally, that should give you the name of the service.

On the other hand, if you never restarted that server and think it was started from the command line (unlikely), you may still have logs for it and/or shell history somewhere with the startup line. So, you need to figure out which account may have run it and look for that. Checking the ownership of the solr.xml file would be a start there, as whatever runs the server would need to have read access to that file (unless it is 777 wide open).

Oh, and /bin/solr is probably coming from Solr Reference Guide, and has been introduced in the most recent version of Solr (4.10). You probably are running something much older.